# Google AdWords API [OperationAccessDenied.ADD_OPERATION_NOT_PERMITTED] when i try create a campaign

Tags: asp.net-core, google-api, google-ads-api

I'm trying to create a Google Bell using the Adwords API, but it throws me the following error ** ADD_OPERATION_NOT_PERMITTED **.
I am not using the MCC Master Id, I am using the id that is on the top right of the adwords website as my ** clientCustomerId **.

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to pull campaigns via the AdWords API? If so, then check your access level in AdWord UI - do you have standard access or read only?

Heres a class you can use to download a list of campaigns in C#:

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-dotnet-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/CSharp/v201806/BasicOperations/GetCampaigns.cs

Comment: yes i can pull the campaigns. how do i check my access level in adword?